# How do i send a link with get values in it to an email?

Tags: php, email, get

I want my site to email a a link to users using passed in variables from get. in the form of  www.test.com/test.php&test=testing+this+is+a+test

but when i do something like this,

```
$msg= "testing".$_GET('details');
```

It spits out "www.test.com/test.php&test=testing this is a test" 
[with spaces and not '+' signs]

Any ideas how i can pass it in unformatted?

Comment: Are you sure that code gives that output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on any string you intend to use as a GET parameter.